# QT-Designer - Selecting overlapping objects, how?

Tags: qt

Is there a way in QT-Designer to see a "DOM Tree" like list of elements inside a window? Otherwise, how can I select an object that's totally overshadowed by another object with identical dimensions?

Can't believe they haven't thought about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Object Inspector should be on the right hand side.

[image]

If not, go to View->Object Inspector

From there, you can select the object by name.

Comment: ah, it was hiding under the "Actions" window. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the "View" menu, check "Object inspector". I think that's what you're looking for.